# Style or inheritance for drawable in android XML resources

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-styles

I have got several vectors with the same root tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="26dp"
    android:height="26dp"
    android:viewportWidth="26.0"
    android:viewportHeight="26.0">
```

to make this code better I wanna back these for attributes into style like this:

```
<style name="vector">

        <item name="android:width"26dp</item>
        <item name="android:height">26dp</item>
        <item name="android:viewportWidth">26.0</item>
        <item name="android:viewportHeight">26.0</item>
    </style>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/vector">
    ...

</vector>
```

But Android Studio says :

> style is unknown attribute.

Is it possible to this?

Comment: Vyacheslav, did you find a solution to this? I'm trying to have my child vector drawable to inherit from a parent vector drawable where the child will just change the color attribute.